# How to send data from nested ViewModel to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am using nested view models to display views based on user roles.

**Model:**

```
public class MainVM {
  //some properties
  public OneVM One {get; set;}
  public TwoVM Two {get; set;}
}

public class OneVM {
   //properties
}

public class TwoVM {
   //properties
}
```

As written [here](https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/multiple-viewmodels-in-a-single-mvc-view/) that only main model is need to be sent controller. I am using Automapper to map properties from received model.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult EditAction(MainVM model){
  var item = db.Table.Find(model.Id);
  //automapper to map
  AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(model.One, item); //does not work

  db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is this the right way to do that? What am I doing wrong here.

**Update:** 
This was the view I was using to render nested view models from partial views

**View:**

```
@model MainVM

@Html.RenderPartial("_OnePartial", Model.One)
```

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6292180/342095 defines an Html helper which will generate the partial view with right names.

Comment: `var result = Mapper.Map<OneVM>(item);`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev `Mapper.Map<OneVM>(item);` but you passed item as a source? While source should be the received `model` through parameter

Comment: Don't you want to convert `item` to `OneVM`?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev No. I updated the code. I want to map properties from received model to `item` and will save the recieved changes in db

Comment: What you mean by **not working?**

Comment: Please specify what exactly is not working to improve your question. Is the problem AutoMapper related or the nested MainVM model not totally filled?

Comment: @annemartijn Debugging took ages. Nested model `One` is not filled.

Comment: The whole nested model was `null` earlier. Than I added initializers for them in constructor of `MainVM` as `this.One = OneVM()`. Now every property in the nested model is null.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Nested model is not being filled

Comment: @LifeH2O The problem probably lies in your HTML. If a model is nested, then the input fields of properties should be like this: `<input type="text" name="model.One.PropertyName" />`

Comment: @annemartijn oh I got it now. I am passing nested model to partial view with `Partial("_partialView", Model.One)` and in there I am using `EditorFor(model=>model.property)`. What is the right construct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5197087/342095 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460150/mvc4-nested-partial-view-loses-model-data suggest using editor templates. I already have many editor templates.

Comment: @LifeH2O If you would improve your question, I could remove the downvote. This will help others having the same difficulties solve their problems.

Answer (score 2):

The value of property `One` will be empty because you are passing an instance of `OneVM` to the partial (not the main model) so the form controls are not correctly named with the prefix (which need to be `name="One.SomeProperty"`).

You have included a link to a `PartialFor()` helper (which works) but don't use it. In the main view it needs to be

```
@Html.PartialFor(m => m.One, "_OnePartial")
```

Which is the equivalent of

```
@Html.Partial("_OnePartial", Model.One, 
    new ViewDataDictionary { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "One" }})
```

Comment: Helper gets called but nothing is rendered. Helper is a generic solution, why should I avoid it? The solution without helper, as you have given, does display the partial view correctly and data is submitted fine.

Comment: It should also be possible to have a generic way to receive and update only those properties which were used in the view.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comments. In you question you use `@Html.RenderPartial("_OnePartial", Model.One)` which is invalid and does nothing - it needs to be `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_OnePartial", Model.One) }`. But even if you used it correctly, this does not add the prefix (by design). As I noted in the first part of my answer, you included a link to a custom helper method named `PartialFor()` which does work if you use it correctly, which is in your case `@Html.PartialFor(m => m.One, "_OnePartial")`

Comment: Also, if you are wanting to generate controls for properties which are complex objects or collections, then you should be using an `EditorTemplate`, not a partial. Just copy the partial into `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/OneVM.cshtml` (note the name of the file must match the name of the class) and in the main view use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.One)` and the generated controls will all be correctly named with the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably lies in your HTML. If a model is nested, then the input fields of properties should be like this:

```html
<input type="text" name="SubModel.PropertyName" />
```

Using HTML helpers, it would look something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubModel.PropertyName)
```

The ASP.NET MVC Action cannot know, that you want to fill your submodel if it's not in your HTML.

Comment: Helpers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488890/asp-net-mvc-partial-views-input-name-prefixes/6292180#6292180 are not working.

Comment: If you really want to use partial views, then you could consider passing the parent model. The answer I gave will work in that scenario. If you don't want to pass the parent model, then you'll probably have to use `@Html.Editor("SubModel.PropertyName", Model.PropertyName)`.