# Type conversion error when model is passed to partial

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I get the following error when I hit the postback:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Test.Models.ProductsModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Test.Models.AttributeModel'**

What I want to achieve is hopefully pretty selfexplanatory with the code below

```
 public class ProductsModel
 {
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public AttributeModel AttributeModel { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model Test.Models.ProductsModel      
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

    @Html.Partial("_Attribute", Model.AttributeModel)

    <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
}
```

**_Attribute.cshtml**

```
@model Test.Models.AttributeModel

<h2>_Attribute</h2>

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Size)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Size)
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ProductsModel model = new ProductsModel { AttributeModel = new AttributeModel() };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductsModel m)
{
    return View(m);
}
```

**EDIT - SOLUTION**

I found that the problem occurs because no input binds to AttributeModel which means that it will be null in ProductsModel, resulting in the follow errouneous statement:

```
@Html.Partial("_Attribute", null)
```

The solution is to use the HTML helper "EditorFor". Have a look at [Complex models and partial views - model binding issue in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197038/complex-models-and-partial-views-model-binding-issue-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: I think I already do that? Have a look at my controller

Comment: Is there anything else in either the `Create` or `_Attribute` views?

Comment: No, I have posted it all. Well beside @ViewBag.Title, but that should be irrelevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem is in your postback action. I would thing that the View that it is getting has `AttributeModel` as `null` so when you are calling the Partial you are actually calling it with `("_Attribute", null)` and if the model is null then it will pass the current model in instead.

You need to make sure you have a valid `AttributeModel` on your `ProductsModel`.

Comment: Well thank you, that is indeed the problem! But the AttributeModel is always null it seems. Why does input not bind to that model in my partial view?

Comment: I'm not sure. The magic of model binding is not always something I fully understand. Perhaps a separate question for that might be in order.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the AttributeModel property of your class like

```
public class ProductsModel
{
   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public AttributeModel AttributeModel { get; set; }
   public ProductsModel()
   {
     this.AttributeModel =new AttributeModel();
    }
}
```

Because initially AttributeModel property is set to null.

Answer (score 0):

The Error is very descriptive.Its telling what is done wrong.

Your partial view requires object of type `Test.Models.AttributeModel` but you are passing object of type `Test.Models.ProductsModel`

Here you have set Model to `Test.Models.AttributeModel`

```
@model Test.Models.AttributeModel

<h2>_Attribute</h2>

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Size)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Size)
```

Change you partial view Model to `Test.Models.AttributeModel` or pass object of type `Test.Models.AttributeModel` from the action.

Comment: But why? Does Model.AttributeModel not return Test.Models.AttributeModel?

Comment: if you show your action as well that will be more easy to help

Comment: I have added it to my question. But the way I am doing it is obviously not the way to do it?

Comment: which one is for partial view?

Comment: _Attribute.cshtml is the partial view

Comment: Well, the error first occur when i click the submit

Comment: Changing the model that the view uses is not the way to fix this problem. The @model shows what model is required so clearly the problem is with the partial's model declaration not matching the model passed in.

Comment: you need to pass whole mode like this: ``@Html.Partial("_Attribute",Model)``

Comment: @Peter: if the problem occurs only after you click (ie after the first postback) then that is vital information that should be edited into your question.

Comment: and in partial view change model to: ``@model Test.Models.ProductsModel``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: That would then pass a ProductsModel into the partial which expects an AttributeModel

Comment: read the second comment, acually issue is that model is property of ProductsModel so its base type is ProductsModel and error will come surely

Comment: You shouldn't need to change any of the `@model` statements though. The fix should be to ensure that the correct model is passed into the view in the first place, not blindly change things to hope they match. The question here is really why is a `ProductsModel` being passed into the partial when I think an `AttributesModel` should be getting passed.

Comment: yes that is little weird but what i suspect is as it is property of ProductModel so it is taking property's base type,

Comment: Thank you guys. I have found a solution. It is updated in the question. I don't know if that is the practice, but it will probably be easier if someone else have the same question.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. The correct object type was passed but it was uninitialized (i.e. null, so the parent object was passed instead)... -1 to reverse the obviously "mistaken" up-vote *you seem to get a lot of*. :)