# Losing partial view model form values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, partial-views

I have a form (using the primary viewmodel) and then a partial view to implement the address portion of the form (secondary viewmodel). When I submit the form, I'm not getting back the values of the inner, partial view part of the form. Not getting any errors, just losing the values of the partial. Code as follows:

"Main" portion of form:

```
@model REMS.ViewModels.AddComplexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Complex";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@{ Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Partials/ActionStatusPartial.cshtml", Model.ActionStatusMessageViewModel); }

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComplex", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Add a New Complex</h4>
    <hr />    
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Partials/AddressFormPartial.cshtml", Model.AddressViewModel)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Owner", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SelectedOwner", Model.Owners, "Select an Owner...")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Partial view of form:

```
@model REMS.ViewModels.AddressViewModel

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address1, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address1, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address2, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address2, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.State, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.State, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Zip, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Zip, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

View Models:

```
public class AddComplexViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "AddressViewModel")]
    public AddressViewModel AddressViewModel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SelectedOwner")]
    public Guid SelectedOwner { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Owners")]
    public SelectList Owners { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ActionStatusMessageViewModel")]
    public ActionStatusViewModel ActionStatusMessageViewModel { get; set; }

    public AddComplexViewModel()
    {
        ActionStatusMessageViewModel = new ActionStatusViewModel();
        AddressViewModel = new AddressViewModel();
    }
}


public class AddressViewModel
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
```

When I submit the form the address values are all null. Am I missing something?

Comment: Partial view is still technically a view, you're not able to get the values from the partial just because it's inside the main view's form. You could use editor templates like outlined here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197038/complex-models-and-partial-views-model-binding-issue-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: That solution worked. Having other issues now but unrelated to this. Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial views are still technically views. You're unable to get the values from the partial just because it is inside of the main view's form.

Look into [Editor Templates](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html), they'll allow you to achieve what you're looking for.

More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197038/complex-models-and-partial-views-model-binding-issue-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 2):

Pass to partial view your main AddComplexViewModel model to generate right names for inputs. I assume that in AddComplex method you take AddComplexViewModel as parameter.

Change in main form:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Partials/AddressFormPartial.cshtml", Model.AddressViewModel)
```

to:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Partials/AddressFormPartial.cshtml", Model)
```

then in partial view change:

```
@model REMS.ViewModels.AddressViewModel
```

to:

```
@model REMS.ViewModels.AddComplexViewModel
```

and each lambda like:

```
m => m.Address1
```

to:

```
m => m.AddressViewModel.Address1
```

whole partial view after edit:

```
@model WebApplication2.Controllers.AddComplexViewModel

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.Address1, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.Address1, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.Address2, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.Address2, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.City, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.City, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.State, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.State, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.Zip, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressViewModel.Zip, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)

Comment: A partial can be called from anywhere, sending the outside Model to it somehow breaks its reason to exist.